# how can I add string to args in va_list

Tags: c

My code is:

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, format); 
vsyslog(severity, format, args);
va_end(args);
```

I want to add extra information before sending message to syslog server. I mean before `vsyslog` the extra information should add at the begining of string that send with vsyslog. How can I do this? or maybe I shoul ask is it possible? I hope I could explain my problem obviously.

Comment: Perhaps you could include the extra string as a prefix or suffix of your `format`?

Comment: As for your assumed solution: You can't. `va_list` is a wrapper around a mechanism to read function parameters, it can be as simple as a pointer into the calling stack. You can't modify the number of parameters once a function was called.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I used in my code is:

```
va_list args;                                                                 
va_start(args, format); 
char *new_format = NULL;
asprintf(&new_format, "%s, %s", my_string, format);
vsyslog(severity, new_format, args); 
free(new_format);   
va_end(args);
```